# I am having an issue with making this calculator work with eval

Tags: javascript, jquery, eval, calculator

I have to make this calculator work with eval however I have tried to make this work multiple times various way any help would work.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".digit").click(function() {
    var num = $(this).text();
    $("#calculation").text(num);
  });

  $(".operator").click(function() {
    var math = $(this).text();
    $("#calculation").text(math);
  });

  $(".clear").click(function() {
    var clear = $(this).text();
    $("#calculation").text("0");
  });
});
```

Comment: what are you trying to do?

Comment: I am trying to make a calculator using the eval (i have never used it before) I am fairly new to jquery and i have used tutorials etc but i cant figure anything out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, let's try this.

First you need to store the expression somewhere. In a global variable, for instance:

```
var expression = "";

$(document).ready(function() {
...
});
```

Then you must append the digits and operators to the expression, evaluate and display the result. Let's make a function for this:

```
function appendChar(char) {
    expression += char;
    var result;
    try {
        result = eval(expression);
    } catch (e) {
        // failure to evaluate
        result = "error";
    }
    $("#calculation").text(result);
}
```

Finally, you must clear the expression with clear is pressed. Here is the whole code:

```
var expression = "";
function appendChar(char) {
    expression += char;
    var result;
    try {
        result = eval(expression);
    } catch (e) {
        // failure to evaluate
        result = "error";
    }
    $("#calculation").text(result);
}

$(document).ready(function() {

    $(".digit, .operator").click(function()    {
        appendChar($(this).text());
    });

    $(".clear").click(function()    {
        expression = "";
        $("#calculation").text("0");
    });
});
```

UPDATE:

To show what's happening, you can display the expression as well as the result:

```
function appendChar(char) {
    expression += char;
    var result;
    try {
        result = eval(expression);
        $("#calculation").text(expression + " = " + result);
    } catch (e) {
        $("#calculation").text(expression);
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks for breaking it down I understand this clearly

Comment: so i understand the above code however how would i make the equal button work when pressed instead of the equation automatically showing

Comment: @CharlieAxsom yeah, I think it will be better with an equal button

Answer (score 0):

You are replacing the text in `#calculation` entirely, instead of concatenating to it to form a mathematical expression.

Try the below code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".digit").click(function() {
    var num = $(this).text();
    var calculation = $("#calculation").text();
    $("#calculation").text(calculation + num);
  });

  $(".operator").click(function() {
    var math = $(this).text();
    var calculation = $("#calculation").text();
    $("#calculation").text(calculation + match);
  });

  // ... remaining code truncated
});
```

After a `=` button is clicked, you can take the text from `#calculation` and pass it to `eval` method as a parameter. You will get your answer.